# Error while creating large TIFF with gdal_merge

Tags: gdal, geotiff-tiff, gdal-merge, bigtiff

I need to merge two TIFFs into one, but the output is larger than 4 GB. So, it needs to be a BigTIFF. But the `"BIGTIFF=YES"` creation option seems to be ignored. Here's the error:

```
$ gdal_merge.py -separate -co "BIGTIFF=YES" -co "COMPRESS=DEFLATE" -o merged.tif vv.tif vh.tif
0...10...20...30...40...50ERROR 1: ZIPDecode:ZLib error:
ERROR 1: TIFFReadEncodedStrip() failed.
ERROR 1: merged.tif, band 1: An error occurred while writing a dirty block from GDALRasterBand::RasterIO
...60...70...80...90...100 - done.
ERROR 1: TIFFAppendToStrip:Maximum TIFF file size exceeded. Use BIGTIFF=YES creation option.
ERROR 1: ZIPDecode:ZLib error:
ERROR 1: TIFFReadEncodedStrip() failed.
```

The output TIFF (which is corrupted) is 4.3 GB whereas the two TIFFs I want to merge are both 1.5 GB.

I also tried without the compression option, but the result is the same. Any idea where this comes from?

Comment: what is your version of GDAL ? I had some issues with 2.3. Also, as a workaround, tou should try "gdalbuildvrt -separate merged.vrt vv.tif vh.tif" then "gdal_translate merged.vrt merged.tif -co BIGTIFF=YES -co COMPRESS=DEFLATE" (I also recommend -co TILED=YES). Finally, consider that working with the vrt is often a good solution in itself (no need to build new tif)

Comment: Remove the double quotes and try again.

Comment: @radouxju I have version 2.4. Indeed, doing what you suggest works fine!

Comment: @user30184 already tried, it doesn't change anything.